# Facebook Page Events - Invite fans?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-events

I am an admin for a Facebook Page for a group I am part of.

I have created an Event and would like to invite all "fans" of the Page to it.  I can't see any way to do this though - I can only invite **my** friends or send an "Update" to fans of the page, which if I understand correctly is kind of like a message but not exactly.

I would really like to send an invitation to everyone because this lets them RSVP to the event, which I don't think is the case with an update.

Is there some magical secret way to do what I want, or is this a glaring omission on the part of Facebook?  (Or is there some other way to achieve what I'm looking for?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the new Groups functionality to achieve this.
Create a group under the same name as your page and think of it as an inner circle to your more dedicated fans. You will then be able to invite group members to the event.

Pages are meant to provide information without being a nuisance to the follower. It is basically an extension of a business or celebrity. The 'fans' term was dropped and replaced with the 'like' term. Users 'like' your page they are not friends/members of your page. It can be a passing penchant. I can decide to like your page today and not like it tomorrow. Hence the way I see it , Facebook Pages can never contact me outside of Facebook i.e. by mail . Potential spam (click-jacking,liking useless pages) headache avoided.

If you really want to use your page you will need to focus on getting more attention to your events by hooking up some fbml and a tab as the default page instead of the wall. Also look into your insights and decide when is the best time/day to update your followers.

Comment: thanks!  glad to know I'm not blind :)  'tis a shame though...