# How did Microsoft invite fans from a particular region to an event?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

https://www.facebook.com/events/633819413306875/

It looks like Microsoft invited a bunch of fans of their page that are from Austin to an event and I want to know how they did that.

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/8100) suggests that one could create a group and then invite people from the group, but if Microsoft has a group that I can join, I'm not seeing it.

And even if they did, how could I invite people on a regional basis?